# NextJs return 404 for every path

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I start the development server I only got 404 Page and the same for all the page, Knowing that  the project was working.

I tried:

- to remove the .next
- to remove the node_modules and reinstalled
- Update "react" and "react/dom"
- Modifies the "next.config.js" to add Page

  pageExtensions: ["page.tsx", "page.ts", "page.jsx", "page.js"],

But without any results.

This package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "format": "prettier . --write --ignore-unknown"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^15.11.1",
    "@contentful/rich-text-types": "^15.11.1",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.6.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "antd": "^4.18.3",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.14",
    "contentful": "^9.1.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "jest": "^27.5.0",
    "next": "12",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.49.0",
    "swiper": "^8.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^6.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.8",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "lint-staged": "^12.1.7",
    "prettier": "2.5.1"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*": "prettier --write --ignore-unknown",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^6.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.11.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "eslint": "8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: what does your pages folder look like?

Comment: Your package.json also doesn't look as if it is auto generated. For example I see dependencies in the lint-staged jobs section

Comment: Yeah it looks like you don't have any page files in your `pages/` directory. See how routing works here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages